# Core Identity - ApplicationController error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm following a turorial: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core/

I have an error in AplpicationController that I'm not sure how to fix.
I would really appreciate some help

In the Index() method below I receive and error on this line:
NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count -- ApplicationRole does not contain a definition for Users...

Here is the ApplicationController class:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel> model = new List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel>();
            model = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleListViewModel
            {
                RoleName = r.Name,
                Id = r.Id,
                Description = r.Description,
                NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
            }).ToList();
            return View(model);
```

Here is the ApplicationRoleListViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreRole.Models
{
    public class ApplicationRoleListViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing something like this:
NumberOfUsers = (r.Users != null) ? r.Users.Count : 0

You can only do a count on a list that is not null. If the list is null, then the count is zero